# ¿Como puedo obtener un atributo al hacer click en un botón dentro de un modal?

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc

Mi problema es el siguiente: necesito obtener el ID de una credencial al hacer click sobre un botón, pero dada la estructura que tengo no sé como encarar el problema.

Método del controlador que recibe el request.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/fisicHost/{id}/credentials", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public List<Credential> credentialsByFisicHost(@PathVariable(value = "id") final Long fisicHostId, ModelMap modelMap){
    FisicHost optionalFisicHost = fisicHostDao.findById(fisicHostId);

    if (optionalFisicHost == null) {
        // Responder con 404
    }
    FisicHost fisicHost = optionalFisicHost;
    return fisicHost.getCredentials();
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="credentialsModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="modal-title">Credenciales</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <table id="credentialsTable">
                    <tr class="row">
                        <th id="modal-user">Usuario</th>
                        <th id="modal-pass">Clave</th>
                        <th id="modal-notes">Notas</th>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(".credentialsButton").click(function(){

    var fisicHostId = $(this).data('fisic-host-id');
    $.get( "/fisicHost/" + fisicHostId + "/credentials", data => {
        console.log(data);

        $('#credentialsTable').empty();

//        var user = document.createElement('th');
//        user.textContent = "USUARIO";

        for (i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
            var fisicHost = data[i];

            var new_row = document.createElement('tr');
            new_row.className = "row fisichost";

            var userCol = document.createElement('td');
            userCol.textContent = fisicHost["user"];
            new_row.append(userCol);

            var passwordCol = document.createElement('td');
            passwordCol.textContent = fisicHost["password"];
            new_row.append(passwordCol);

            var notesCol = document.createElement('td');
            notesCol.textContent = fisicHost["notes"];
            new_row.append(notesCol);

            var editButton = document.createElement('button');
            editButton.textContent = "EDITAR"
            new_row.append(editButton);

            var deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
            deleteButton.id = buttonId;
            deleteButton.textContent = "BORRAR"
            new_row.append(deleteButton);

            $("#credentialsTable").append(new_row);

  // ACA ESTA EL TEMA

            $(deleteButton).on('click', () => {
                var credentialId = fisicHost["id"];
                console.log(credentialId);
//            $.post( "/fisicHost/" + credentialId + "/credentials", data => {});
            });
        }

        $('#credentialsModal').modal('show');

    }).fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.error(error);
        alert('No se pudieron cargar las credenciales.');
    });
});

$('#credentialsModal').bind('hide', function () {
   $('#credentialsModal tr.fisichost').remove();
});
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando el usuario haga click sobre el botón **BORRAR** que se observa en la imagén del modal, quiero obtener el ID de esa credencial para poder usarla en el back-end.

El problema recide en que siempre que hago click en el botón me toma el ID de la última credencial cargada, se ve que recorre todo el for() y luego toma el ID de la última, cuando yo lo que quiero es que tome el ID de la credencial en la que el botón fue clickeado. Osea, si se clickea el botón borrar de la credencial dos me tome el ID 2, no el último.

En consola, el objeto **data** (que son las credenciales) en este caso se ve así:

```
[…]
0: {…}
id: 2
notes: "notas"
password: "pass"
role: "null"
user: "usuario"
__proto__: Object { … }
1: {…}
id: 3
notes: "notasssss"
password: "pass"
role: "null"
user: "usuario"
__proto__: Object { … }
length: 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
$(".credentialsButton").click(function(){

    var fisicHostId = $(this).data('fisic-host-id');
    $.get( "/fisicHost/" + fisicHostId + "/credentials", data => {
        console.log(data);

        $('#credentialsTable').empty();

        for (i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
            var fisicHost = data[i];

            var new_row = document.createElement('tr');
            new_row.className = "row fisichost";

            var userCol = document.createElement('td');
            userCol.textContent = fisicHost["user"];
            new_row.append(userCol);

            var passwordCol = document.createElement('td');
            passwordCol.textContent = fisicHost["password"];
            new_row.append(passwordCol);

            var notesCol = document.createElement('td');
            notesCol.textContent = fisicHost["notes"];
            new_row.append(notesCol);

            var editButton = document.createElement('button');
            editButton.id =`edi-${fisicHost["id"]}`;
            editButton.textContent = "EDITAR"
            new_row.append(editButton);

            var deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
            deleteButton.id = `del-${fisicHost["id"]}`;
            deleteButton.textContent = "BORRAR"
            new_row.append(deleteButton);

            $("#credentialsTable").append(new_row);

  // ACA ESTA EL TEMA

        }

        $('#credentialsModal').modal('show');

    }).fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.error(error);
        alert('No se pudieron cargar las credenciales.');
    });
});

$("#credentialsTable").on('click',"button[id^='edi-']",  (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.id)
    //var credentialId = fisicHost["id"];
    //  $.post( "/fisicHost/" + credentialId + "/credentials", data => {});
});

$("#credentialsTable").on('click',"button[id^='del-']",  (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.id)
    //var credentialId = fisicHost["id"];
    //  $.post( "/fisicHost/" + credentialId + "/credentials", data => {});
});

$('#credentialsModal').bind('hide', function () {
   $('#credentialsModal tr.fisichost').remove();
});
```

explicamos:

```
$("#credentialsTable").on('click',"button[id^='del-']",  (e) => {
```

seleccinamos el id $("#credentialsTable") que es el unico elemento estatico
a partir de hay buscamos el button que tenga un elemento id que empieze
con del- esto bucara
 `< buttom id="del-1"> o < buttom id="del-2">` etc..
igual para el button edit- le pasamos el evento con e al dar click `e.target` no regresara el button al cual se le dio click unicamente y a partir de hay obtenemos su id 
referencia:
[selector de attributos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Selectores_atributo)
el `del-${fisicHost["id"]}`; es un concatenacion de emacs6 por plantilla:
referencia:
[plantilla emacs6](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings)

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta !!! Con tu código no se porque no me abre el modal que tiene credenciales, el que está vacio me lo abre perfecto, pero el que tiene las credenciales cargadas no lo abre, debe estar pisando algo o debe estar mal hecho por mi de fondo .... (seguro)

Comment: ahora si, no se que cambiaste, ya me anda :)

Comment: cambie buttonId por fisicHost["id"] para que fuera dinamico y no fijo! el valor!

Comment: me podrías explicar el código ?? Hay simbolos raros que no entiendo ... id^='del-' ... y no se porque por consola me sale del-y el numero ... solo quiero el numero

Comment: Podrías modificarlo para que solo me imprima el numero ?? Sin los prefijos del y edi ... lo estuve tocando pero no me salió y no la quiero cagar .. mientras investigo que hace lo que pusiste porque no entiendo mucho

Comment: el del y el edit son para hacer referencia a que es lo que vas a hacer si le dejas solo id="n" sera dificil saber a cual button hace referencia tendrias que obtener su attibuto innerText con esto divides delete de edit

Comment: claro, es que necesito el numero del ID si o si para poder mandarlo al back-end como viene y buscar esa credencial por id .... que me recomendas que haga entonces ?? Una nueva variable y le recorto el edi y el del ??

Comment: ya lo hice, muchas gracias por tu ayuda y tu tiempo <3

Comment: le haces un newid = e.target.id.slice(4) esto removera los 4 primeros elementos osea edi-  y el del- dejando solo los numeros!

Answer (score 0):

Y si al boton borrar le agregas un atributo con el id, podrias hacerlo de esta forma:

```
var deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
deleteButton.id = buttonId;
deleteButton.textContent = "BORRAR"
deleteButton.setAttribute("data-id", fisicHost["id"]);
new_row.append(deleteButton);
```

Luego en el on click

```
$(deleteButton).on('click', () => {
    var credentialId = $(this).data("id");
    console.log(credentialId);
    //$.post( "/fisicHost/" + credentialId + "/credentials", data => {});
});
```

De esta forma cada boton guarda su id, por que la forma como lo estas haciendo es seguro que siempre se queda con el ultimo var `fisicHost["id"]` del recorrido.

Comment: Hola y gracias por responder. Copie el código que me pusiste y le agregué esta línea:   deleteButton.id = fisicHost["id"]; pero en la consola cuando imprimo me tira "undefined" ...

Comment: cuando levantes el modal, presiona f12 o abre la consola del explorador y verifica en cada uno de los botones si el atributo data-id existe.

Comment: si, lo peor es que si existe, pero luego me dice undefined :/

Comment: si sacas el `$(deleteButton).on('click' ...)` fue del for, a cada boton le agregas una clase btnDelete. de esta forma fuera del for mandas a suscribir el evento click de los botones borrar. quedaria asi: `$(document).on("click", ".btnDelete", () => { ... });`